# Randomly select each type of data value and return index of selected

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array: `y = np.array([2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])`
Given a data configuration `config = {2: 3, 0:2, 1: 1}`

I want to randomly select and return an index containing data of the form in the configuration.
**Expected output:** `index_returned =[0, 5, 11, 1, 2, 6]`. This represents indices of elements presented in the dictionary. Here `2 corresponds to [0,5,11], 0 corresponds to [1,2] and 1 corresponds to 6` as indicated in config

### My solution

```
index_of_all_0 = np.where(x==0)[0]
index_of_all_1 = np.where(x==1)[0]
index_of_all_2 = np.where(x==2)[0]

selected_0 = np.random.choice(index_of_all_0, config[0])
selected_1 = np.random.choice(index_of_all_1, config[1])
selected_2 = np.random.choice(index_of_all_2, config[2])

selected = np.concatenate([selected_0, selected_1, selected_2], axis=0)
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this? This solution looks verbose. Also, if I have an arbitrary number of items in my `config`, I don't want to use a *for loop*. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I think using a for loop is inevitable. Could you please clarify why you don't want to use one?

Comment: For loops don't get enough credit nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

If there are an arbitrary number of items in `config` you will need to iterate over `config` one way or another.  A list comprehension is one way, but it's a `for` loop under the hood:

```
selected = np.concatenate([
    np.random.choice(np.where(y == x)[0], config[x]) for x in sorted(config)
], axis=0)
```

The example above uses `sorted(config)` which will return the results in ascending order, but it wasn't clear from your question whether you wanted them in that order or in the order they appear in `config` (which is only guaranteed in Python 3, of course).  Your example result is in dictionary order, but your example code would sort them.